# Read data from IncomingMessage without consuming in Node.js (Hapi.js)

Tags: node.js, stream, request, hapi.js

In a Node.js server, the requests are instances of [IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage). In turn, `IncomingMessage` implements the [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface.

If we want to output the whole request body, we should implement something like this:

```
req.on('data', chunk => {
   console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```

But, this piece of code consumes the data in the stream and I need the data to remain in the stream to be consumed later. Is there any way to read the data from the stream without consuming it?

If not, is it possible to re-queue the data to stream?

In my case, I'm using Hapi.js. The request stream can be accessed via `request.raw.req`. My code looks like this:

```
const server = Hapi.server({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        var req = request.raw.req;    // Get the IncomingMessage

        req.on('data', chunk => {
           console.log(chunk.toString());
        });
        return 'Hello, world!';
    }
});
server.start();
```

Comment: concat chunk.toString() to a string outside of the .on data callback scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following route options does the trick:

```
options: {
    payload: {
        output: 'data',
        parse: false
    }
}
```

This forces Hapijs to read the payload and output it as data, i. e., `request.payload` will be a `Buffer` instead of a stream.

The parse option is optional. When set to false, Hapijs will ignore the content-type of the request and will not try to parse it.